# Foreground service doesn't work i LG K10 2017 android 7.0 Device

Tags: android, foreground-service

Hi so i have Android APP that need to start Foreground service and it works fine in Huawei and Sony and Samsung devices ... in LG K10 2017 android 7.0 device the service doesn't start!! no notification shown please let me know if any one have similar problem or have any idea about solve of the problem. Thanks

```
   public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        //   if (shared.Readbool("work_in_bg"))
        RegisterForegroundService();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(request_new_orders));
        thread.Start();
        background_active = true;
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

 void RegisterForegroundService()
    {
        ongoing = new Notification(Resource.Drawable.SmartDeliveryAppIcon, "Smart Delivery");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop| ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 56, intent, 0);
        ongoing.SetLatestEventInfo(this, "Smart Delivery", "waiting ....", pendingIntent);
        StartForeground((int)NotificationFlags.ForegroundService, ongoing);
    }
```

Comment: post your code here please

Comment: i edited the question